# Webpack Code Splitting: Invalid configuration object

Tags: webpack

**What is the current behavior?**

> Invalid configuration object. Webpack has been initialised using a configuration object that does not match the API schema.
>    - configuration.entry should be one of these:
>      function | object { : non-empty string | [non-empty string] } | non-empty string | [non-empty string]

**If the current behavior is a bug, please provide the steps to reproduce.**

- Setup multiple entry points with object schema
  `object = { import string | [string], dependOn string | [string], filename string }`
- Run webpack command

**What is the expected behavior?**

Support [documented schema](https://webpack.js.org/guides/code-splitting/).

**Other relevant information:**

- Webpack version:  4.41.6
- Operating System: MacOS Mojave, Ubuntu 1.18 (Linux 4.15)

Comment: see: https://github.com/webpack/webpack.js.org/issues/3592

Answer (score 4, accepted):

NPM Tag at top is not the version of the documentation.

Documentation target master, which is under v5 (confusing).

see: https://github.com/webpack/webpack.js.org/issues/3592
[image]